# Quantification over actions

Tags: artificial-intelligence, logic

Looking for examples that show me how to quantify over actions (and perhaps fluents?) in situation calculus (Reiter 2001).

I understand the difference between actions, fluents and situations, but why do they need to be represented in 2nd order logic? Why not use first order? Can you please explain?

Comment: Any help is extremely appreciated !

Comment: The situation and event calculi _are_ first order.  Do you have a reference to someone saying that you need 2nd order logic to work with them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

All but a few formulas used to encode a dynamic world require Second Order Logic (SOL).  In particular,

- the [properties of the] Initial State
- the Action Preconditions
- the Action Effects
- the Successor State axioms (used to circumvent the "Frame problem")

**can all be expressed with First Order Logic (FOL)**.
With some domains it may be *convenient* -and more concise- to use SOL for the above items, but AFAIK, it is always possible to convert such SOL to FOL *in the context of the items listed above*, for a finite domain, and hence SOL is not *necessary* (again, for the above items).

Typically the need for SOL with Situation Calculus only comes from some of the "**Foundational axioms**" such as the axiom to perform induction on Situations.

Furthermore, depending on the particular application, one may not need the SOL-based Foundational axiom(s) and hence the whole world can be exclusively described in terms of FOL.
I'm not a specialist in the field, but I think that in many cases, for the purpose of [Logical] Filtering, Planning, Temporal Projection, we can do away with the need for induction and hence only rely on FOL only.